# MySQL SELECT with unknown columnname

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I need a query like this: `SELECT id FROM database.table;`
But I don't have the columnnames of the primary keys because the query must be universal for more tables. So I tried so make a query like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT k.COLUMN_NAME AS pk_old
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
    AND t.table_schema='database'
    AND t.table_name='table')as pk FROM database.table;
```

But instead of a list with the primary key values of that table like 1,2,3,4... I get a list with id,id,id,id....
What can I do to get the values of the primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use prepare statement to get it

**generate the Query**

```
SELECT
  CONCAT( 'SELECT ',
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME,' AS FIELD_',ORDINAL_POSITION)) ,
  ' FROM ', TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME,' ORDER BY ',
  GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)) INTO @query
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE

WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourSchema'
AND
  TABLE_NAME = 'YorTable'
AND 
  CONSTRAINT_NAME='PRIMARY'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

**verify it (only for test)**

```
SELECT @query;
```

**execute the PREPARE STATEMENT**

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

**DROP it**

```
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot simply ged the column names in a subquery as data and use them as part of the select list in the outer query. SQL does not work this way. You need to assemble your query either in a program outside of MySQL or using [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

So, you query the column names in a separate query an place them into a variable a string and then you create the select statement as string by concatenating the various parts of the sql statement, and then create, execute, and destroy the prepared statement.